# Issue with Playwright running multiple workers and executing hooks multiple times

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I'm experiencing an unexpected behavior with Playwright when running tests with multiple workers. According to the Playwright documentation, the `beforeAll` hook should be executed ONCE PER WORKER. However, I'm observing that the hook is being executed multiple times, resulting in duplicated log messages.

I have a simple test setup with the following structure:

```
test.beforeAll( async({browser}) => {
    console.log("should be before all tests")
});

test.beforeEach( async()=>{
    console.log('should be before Each test')
})

test.afterAll(async() => {
    console.log('should be after all tests')
});

test('test case',async () => {
});

test('test case 2',async () => {
});
```

Expected behavior per worker should be: one console.log before, two console.logs (once per test) and one console.log after.

Received behavior:

```
Running 8 tests using 4 workers
[chromium] › loginAndNavigate.spec.ts:65:5 › test case 2
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
[chromium] › loginAndNavigate.spec.ts:60:5 › test case 1
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
[firefox] › loginAndNavigate.spec.ts:60:5 › test case 1
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
[firefox] › loginAndNavigate.spec.ts:65:5 › test case 2
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
[webkit] › loginAndNavigate.spec.ts:60:5 › test case 1
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
[webkit] › loginAndNavigate.spec.ts:65:5 › test case 2
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
[Mobile Safari] › loginAndNavigate.spec.ts:60:5 › test case 1
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
[Mobile Safari] › loginAndNavigate.spec.ts:65:5 › test case 2
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
```

As you can see, each message is being printed multiple times.

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I've already checked my Playwright configuration(where the number of workers is set to 4). I'm using the latest version of Playwright

Comment: I'm facing this exact scenario. I would assume at least in a test suite consisting of multiple tests in 1 file that a beforeAll would only be performed once. The 2 workarounds I can think of is separating the tests into their own tests file so that it still processes in parallel but that would require a global setup and teardown. Or do serial mode for this 1 test file. If there are other test files, then it'll still be parallel depending on number of workers.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this is expected behavour. As you have set number of workers to 4, `beforeAll` will potentially run up to 4 times per browser. The `beforeAll` hook is also done before each new browser.

To demonstrate, in the run below, I have changed to max 2 workers and are running 4 tests in 2 different browsers:

```
Running 8 tests using 2 workers

  ✓  1 [chrome web] › multipleworkers.spec.ts:19:5 › test case 3 @1 (1ms)
  ✓  2 [chrome web] › multipleworkers.spec.ts:15:5 › test case @1 (1ms)
should be before all tests
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
should be before Each test
  ✓  3 [chrome web] › multipleworkers.spec.ts:17:5 › test case 2 @1 (0ms)
  ✓  4 [chrome web] › multipleworkers.spec.ts:21:5 › test case 4 @1 (0ms)
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
  ✓  5 [firefox web] › multipleworkers.spec.ts:19:5 › test case 3 @1 (1ms)
  ✓  6 [firefox web] › multipleworkers.spec.ts:15:5 › test case @1 (1ms)
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
  ✓  7 [firefox web] › multipleworkers.spec.ts:17:5 › test case 2 @1 (0ms)
should be before all tests
should be before Each test
  ✓  8 [firefox web] › multipleworkers.spec.ts:21:5 › test case 4 @1 (0ms)
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
should be before Each test
should be after all tests
```

Here, beforeAll are run 4 times; 2 workers and 2 different browsers while beforeEach are run 8 times.

Answer (score 0):

### Serial Mode

You may run tests in [serial mode](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#serial-mode) , if you need to run beforeAll just once:

```
// Annotate entire file as serial.
test.describe.configure({ mode: 'serial' });

test.beforeAll( async({browser}) => {
    console.log("should be before all tests")
});

test.beforeEach( async()=>{
    console.log('should be before Each test')
})

test.afterAll(async() => {
    console.log('should be after all tests')
});

test('test case',async () => {
});

test('test case 2',async () => {
});
```

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#serial-mode